# Interpolate line not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst, interpolation

I'm just doing a basic topograph and the interpolate line tool does not work. The DEM is selected and I even made a hillshade to see if that would solve the problem. After I finish the line and double click the line disappears. There is no error message, just a sound as if I was clicking on the wrong window but there are no other windows open. I've restarted GIS, I've made a new map, I've changed where the topo data goes, I've deactivated and reactivated 3D analyst and I've changed the coordinate system to a new one and back to the original and it still does not work.

Comment: what version of arcmap are you using?

Comment: You said "There is no error message, just a sound as if I was clicking on the wrong window but there are no other windows open."  When I hear of symptoms like this I usually try/suggest doing this, in this order, until I reach the one that works: 1. Re-start ArcMap 2. Reboot 3. Repair ArcMap 4. Uninstall/reinstall ArcMap.